# Escaping ' (Single Quote/aprostrophe) not working

Tags: javascript, escaping

This is my code to escape

```
E = {
    "\x26": "\x26amp;",
    "\x3c": "\x26lt;",
    "\x3e": "\x26gt;",
    '"': "\x26quot;",
    "'": "\x26#39;",
    "/": "\x26#x2F;"
};

function myescape(a) {
    return a.replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function(a) {return E[a] })
};
```

The problem here is, when I escape following:
`'!@#$%^&*()_+=-:"'`

It generates following:
`'!@#$%^&amp;*()-=+_';&quot;'`

So, basically all the characters are getting escaped. But, single quote is getting rendered as it is. Any clue how to get past this?

I also tried to added following meta tag (dint work)

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: When you were asking your question (and the 13 before it), to the right of the text area was a big orange **How to Format** box. Worth a read. There was also a toolbar with all sorts of formatting aids above it, and a **[?]** buton with helpful information. There was also a preview area underneath showing exactly what your question would look like. Please use these tools so your code can be correctly presented in your question, complete with syntax highlighting, etc.

Comment: okay...anyways I dont see much difference...

Comment: The difference is that there aren't random backticks in your code anymore, and the code has useful syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem here is, when I escape following: `'!@#$%^&*()_+=-:"'`
>
> It generates following: `'!@#$%^&amp;*()-=+_';&quot;'`

No, it doesn't; the single quotes around the string are string delimiters, not part of the contents of the string. If they were in the **contents** of the string, they'd get replaced, too:

```js
E = {
    "\x26": "\x26amp;",
    "\x3c": "\x26lt;",
    "\x3e": "\x26gt;",
    '"': "\x26quot;",
    "'": "\x26#39;",
    "/": "\x26#x2F;"
};

function myescape(a) {
    return a.replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function(a) {return E[a] })
};

snippet.log(myescape("'!@#$%^&*()_+=-:\"'"));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

This is a Community Wiki because it's basically a comment with code, although it does actually answer the question as well.

Comment: thank you for the response. But it works if I replace `"'": "\x26#39;",` with `"'": "tilde",`

Comment: @SanTosh: See above, it works regardless. If you're seeing it not work, it's related to code you haven't shown.